# Brake disc looks to be damaged, should this have passed MOT?

Tags: vw, brake-rotor, mot, tiguan

I have recently purchased a VW tiguan 2015/2016 2.0 tdi had it less than a week.
had a screw in the rear tyre, went to have tyre repaired, while the wheel was off I looked at the brake disc and it looked to be wearing unevenly, pic attached.[image: picture of break disc]
my question is, should this have passed an MOT with no advisory? the MOT was done before we picked it up last weekend. I'd like to know so I can react accordingly when speaking to the garage.

thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you are in the UK referring to the test as an MOT?

The small amount of rust on that disc is not an issue for the MOT.  Each brake is tested on a rolling road to ensure that they meet the required braking force, yours must have passed this test.  The wheel is not removed for the MOT, so the disc may not even be visible to the tester while the test is performed.

The rusted area will gradually get bigger and may then fail a future test.

Comment: thanks Howie, I wondered if the ring of rust between the thin outer smooth part the thick inner smooth part was an indication it wasn't set correctly. but you've helped ease my mind. thank you